# SAP BPC get content of AppPublication folder

Tags: web-services, xhtml, soapui, sap-erp, sap-bw

Are there anyone that have tried to get the content of the folder called AppPublication in SAP BPC?

I have some files that I have published using SAP BPC ePublish -> Web Ready File

Now I want to create a list using XHTML that contains all the files that are published.

I have been experimenting with the following web services

- /OSoft/Proxy/ContentsProxy/ContentsProxy.asmx
- /OSoft/Proxy/StateManageProxy/ContentStateManageProxy.asmx

I seem only to get one result out of these:

> HTTP response: 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have also tried to use SoapUI, and getting the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 10:12:22 GMT
Content-Length: 435

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
   <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> Object variable or With block variable not set.</faultstring>
   <detail />
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know what this problem could be?

Or is there a better way to get this list?

Comment: If you use the MS platform version, you can directly retrieve the folder contents from the IIS folder (typically C:\PC_MS\...)